# Combine elements of a list

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I need a little help to combine elements of my list without duplicate elements.

Source:

```
var data = new List<string>();
data.Add("A");
data.Add("B");
data.Add("C");
data.Add("D");
```

Expected result, a list of Tuples:

`List<Tuple<string,string>>`

> Tuple(A,B)
>
> Tuple(A,C)
>
> Tuple(A,D)
>
> Tuple(B,C)
>
> Tuple(B,D)
>
> Tuple(C,D)

Ignored Tuples:

> Tuple(B,A) - Because there is A,B in list.
>
> Tuple(C,A)
>
> Tuple(C,B)
>
> Tuple(D,A)
>
> Tuple(D,B)
>
> Tuple(D,C)

Comment: Where are you adding tuples in your example?

Comment: I did this exact same thing in JavaScript last week for a different question

Comment: why don't you include it in your post. you can use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42418555/edit) button below your post to add information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
 var tupleList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
 for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
 {
     for (int j = i + 1; j < data.Count; j++)
     {
         tupleList.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(data[i], data[j]));
     }
 }
```

Comment: YES! nested loops is not good, but works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution, but S&O is not place for solving homeworks (at least show your attempts to solve problem):

```
        var data = new List<string>(4) { "A", "B", "C", "D" }; // unique keys
        var tuples = new List<Tuple<string, string>>() { Capacity = data.Count * (data.Count + 1) / 2};
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; ++i)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < data.Count; ++j)
                tuples.Add(Tuple.Create(data[i], data[j]));
```